# PHP SQL Injection bind dynamic variables in statement for UPDATE

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, bind, sql-injection

I am trying to be safe from Sql Injection by doing prepared statements + binding on all Database save/update/query actions.
But I got stuck in the moment in which the table name + user_id are variables. code:

```
// ALL USUAL $dbc MySqli DATABASE CONNECTION - then code statement prepare:
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE ".$tablex." SET logo=?, last_mod=? WHERE ".$table_id."=?");
// or: $stmt = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE $tablex SET logo=?, last_mod=? WHERE $table_id=?"); same thing 

$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $log_logo, $last_mod, $user_id);

// execute and do some checking
$status_save = $stmt->execute();
if ($status_save === false) {trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);}
```

It has worked fine so far as long as $tablex and $table_id were known. Now they can have different names, and using a variable sets things wrong. What am I doing wrong here? Tx.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not bind table or field names. If you want to use variables there, you have to be extremely careful about validating them. I would recommend building a whitelist array of possible names, and then check that the given variable is in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Alex.

Comment: On a subsequent debugging, I found out I had an error on some other code on the top of the page. Now it's working ok with

    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE $tablex SET logo=?, last_mod=? WHERE $table_id=?");